# Swift Multi Selection TableView occurs error while unselecting rows

Tags: ios, swift

i have a problem with my multi selection table view. I receive an error if i unselect the previous select rows with an different order than i have selected it. It says

> Index out of range
>   I receive this error while i'm trying to remove an item of my array. Here is my Code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark{
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        //Line above occurs the error
        checkedCategories.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }else{
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        checkedCategories.append(allcategories[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

Comment: Show declaration of `checkedCategories`. Is it set or array?

Comment: yes, it is a Array[Object]

Answer (score 0):

You always adding items in the end of array (so index of added item is `checkedCategories.count - 1`). But deleting by index of row.
So instead of row index, get index of added category and then remove by this index

```swift
if let index = checkedCategories.firstIndex(of: allcategories[indexPath.row]) {
    checkedCategories.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: Hey, i cannot use this code, xcode is throwing different errors.

Comment: Maybe its because it is checkedCategories is [SellerObject]

Comment: @MarkusGerlach perhaps you could share what errors it throwing?